# Word to html conversion using php

Tags: php, html, ms-word

I am working on a linux server.
I need to convert a word file to html and show as it is shown in word document.

Is possible to convert it in a Linux machine without .NET support?
Anyone have any idea about that,please help me.
I have tried many scripts,but it will only show the text content without its alignment.

Comment: Godspeed, son. Godspeed.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy,Have any idea about this question?is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i got solution with Abiword

Install abiword with

```
 yum install abiword
```

Then,here is the code

```
<?php
 $path=getcwd();
 $cmd  = 'abiword --to=html '.$path.'/test.docx';
 exec($cmd);
 $content=file_get_contents($path.'/test.html');
 unlink($path.'/test.html');

echo urldecode($content);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use LibreOffice from the command line.

```
soffice --headless --convert-to html file.doc
```

In PHP, just use shell_exec or something to call that.